# find length of a fixed width file wtih a little twist

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

Hi Wonderful People/My Gurus and all kind-hearted  people.

I've a fixed width file and currently i'm trying to find the length of those rows that contain x bytes. I tried couple of awk commands but, it is not giving me the result that i wanted. My fixed width contains 208bytes, but there are few rows that don't contain 208 bytes. I"m trying to discover those records that doesn't have 208bytes.

this cmd gave me the file length

```
awk '{print length;exit}' file.text
```

here i tried to print rows that contain 101 bytes, but it didn't work.

```
awk '{print length==101}' file.text
```

Any help/insights here would be highly helpful

Comment: You've been on this forum long enough and posted enough questions that you should know better by now than to post a question without sample input/output. If not though - see [ask].

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for replying. Actually i don't have  a way to put out a sample fixed width file here. that's why i couldn't attach sample datasets here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'length() < 208' file
```

Well, length() gives you the number of *characters*, not *bytes*. This number can differ in unicode context. You can use the `LANG` environment variable to force awk to use *bytes*:

```
LANG=C awk 'length() < 208' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'print "$.:", length if length != 208' -- file.text
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from the input before processing it and adds them to `print`

The one-liner will print line number ($.) and the length of the line for each line whose length is different than 208.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `gawk`, then it's no issue, even in typical `UTF-8` locale mode :

```
length(s)         =  # chars native to locale, 
                     # typically that means # utf-8 chars

match(s, /$/) - 1 = # raw bytes   # this also work for pure-binary
                                  # inputs, without triggering 
                                  # any error messages in gawk Unicode mode
```

Best illustrated by example :

```
0000000        3347498554      3381184647      3182945161       171608122

           :   Ɔ  **   Ǉ  **   Ȉ  **   ɉ  **  㷽  **  **   : 210   :  \n

          072 306 206 307 207 310 210 311 211 343 267 275 072 210 072 012
           :   ?  86   ?  87   ?  88   ?  89   ?   ?   ?   :  88   :  nl

           58 198 134 199 135 200 136 201 137 227 183 189  58 136  58  10
           3a  c6  86  c7  87  c8  88  c9  89  e3  b7  bd  3a  88  3a  0a

0000020

 # gawk profile, created Sat Oct 29 20:32:49 2022
 BEGIN {
 1          __ = "\306\206\307\207\310"  (_="\210") \
                  "\311\211\343\267\275"

 1      print "",__,_
 1      STDERR = "/dev/stderr"

 1      print (             match(_,  /$/) - 1, "_" ) > STDERR  # *A
 1      print ( length(__), match(__, /$/) - 1      ) > STDERR  # *B

 1      print (     (__~_), match(__, (_) ".*")     ) > STDERR  # *C
 1      print (     RSTART, RLENGTH                 ) > STDERR  # *D
}

1 | _   *A   # of bytes off "_" because it was defined as 0x88 \210
5 | 11  *B   # of chars of "__", and 
             # of bytes of it : 
             #                   4 x 2-byte UC 
             #                +  1 x 3-byte UC = 11

1 | 3   *C   # does byte \210 exist among larger string (true/1),
             # and which unicode character is 1st to 
             # contain \210 - the 3rd one, by original definition

3 | 3   *D   # notice I also added a ".*" to the tail of this match() :
             # if the left-side string being tested is valid UTF-8,
             # then this will match all the way to the end of string,
             # inclusive, in which you can deduce :
             #
             #  "\210 first appeared in 3rd-to-last utf-8 character"
```

Combining that inferred understanding :

```
RLENGTH    = "3 chars to the end, inclusive",
```

with knowledge of how many to its left :

```
RSTART - 1 = "2 chars before",
```

yields a total count of `3 + 2` = `5`, affirming `length()`'s result